# Hive Database Corrupted

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm a novice. What are the steps to be taken in an event of Database corruption in Hive? Is there a way to take Database backup and recover? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you using metastore service ? using that you can locate the Schema of the Tables present in the Hive!!

Comment: Yes. Could you please direct me or send a link where I can learn more on how its done?